# Inject bash condition in command parameter

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I would like to execute a single command that injects the result of a logical operation as argument parameter.
Basically the condition acts as a ternary operator `$VAR ? 40 : 30` and the outcome is set as the parameter

When $VAR is 'true' the following command needs to be executed:
`pytest --cov-fail-under=40`

I tried something like

`pytest --cov-fail-under=${[[ $VAR = 'true' ]] && 40 || 80} tests/`

but I am getting a  **bad substitution** error

Comment: all good below, or you can do `... $( case "$var" in true ) echo 40 ;; * ) echo 80 ;; esac ) ...` Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may output the value.

```
pytest --cov-fail-under=$(if [[ $VAR = 'true' ]]; then echo 40; else echo 80; fi) tests/
```

Comment: `value: '$(if'` you are not running it inside a shell.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has a ternary operator, but it can only be used in arithmetic expressions, so you can't use it when comparing strings.

You'll need to set a variable and then substitute that.

```
if [[ $VAR = true ]]
then fail_under=40
else fail_under=80
fi
pytest --cov-fail-under="$fail_under" tests/
```

Comment: As far as I know, multiple commands can't be done within a Pipfile script.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend `pytest` and customize setting the `cov_fail_under` value. Create a `conftest.py` file in your project or test root dir with the following contents:

```python
import os
import pytest


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    cov_plugin = config.pluginmanager.get_plugin("_cov")
    var = os.environ.get("VAR", None)
    # allow user to override the value from command line by passing `--cov-fail-under=x`
    if cov_plugin is not None and config.option.cov_fail_under is None:
        value = 40 if var == "true" else 30
        cov_plugin.options.cov_fail_under = value
```

Now running e.g.

```
$ export VAR=true
$ pytest --cov=stuff
```

will apply `cov_fail_under = 40` automatically, while running with `VAR` unset or `VAR=false` will use 30 as default value. To override the value with `x`, pass `--cov-fail-under=x` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your bash snippet:

First problem: `${}` is the syntax for specifying a variable name. In other words, `${something}` === `$something`

Second problem: `&&` and `||` must be followed by a command. `[[ $VAR = 'true' ]] && 40` means "if $VAR is 'true' *execute* command `40`.

So your line should be like this:

```sh
pytest --cov-fail-under=$([[ $VAR = 'true' ]] && echo 40 || echo 80) tests/
```

Ternary operator in bash works only within `(( ))` and only for numeric values.

(Also, this has got nothing to do with pytest per se; I'm removing that tag.)

Comment: @room13 you never mentioned pipenv. What I shared was for bash, as you have tagged your question with, and it worked. If the problem is with pipenv that's a different matter altogether and you should have mentioned that in your question.